# How to reduce .ipa file size of IOS build in Flutter?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I have created an IOS build for flutter for the app store and generated its archive which resulted in a huge **90 MB .ipa** file. I searched a lot on the net that how can I reduce IPA file size but didn't got any suitable answers. I tried several methods like :

1. **flutter clean** command in project terminal and then used **flutter build ios** command but it didn't reduce the size.
2. I checked the option for Strip Swift Symbols but it only reduced 1 or 2 MB of size.

Does switching my Xcode project from Swift to Objective-C will reduce my .ipa file size?
I am using several third party libraries in my Flutter app, are they responsible for this huge size?

```
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  gradient_app_bar: ^0.1.3
  url_launcher: ^5.1.2
  easy_localization: ^1.3.0+1
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  connectivity: ^0.4.4
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
  carousel_slider: ^1.3.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.1+4
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^0.1.5+1
```

Comment: I don't have an answer to this, it may be possible to reduce it. Just an FYI, you are going to have a difficult / impossible time trying to get a hybrid/cross-platform app to be the same size as a native app. This is a well documented downside to using tools like Flutter, react-native etc. For best performance and download sizes you need to go native

Comment: Yes, these hybrid frameworks can't replace native apps in terms of performance and size but I need to create apps through single codebase for Android and IOS. I didn't knew that flutter will generate this much huge .ipa file. Is there any way I can convert Swift codes used in Flutter to Objective-C so that it can reduce the .ipa file size?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using `--split-debug-info=` at the end of your build command?

Answer (score 1):

As of Flutter 1.17

you will find a 20% app size reduction,

Also Obfuscating you code will decrease your app size 
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate

Tip! in flutter 1.17 they improves app performance by 50% on iOS

Answer (score 0):

Late, but still, even when i tried

> flutter build ipa

command, ipa file generated is around 90mb

So i tried creating archive with xcode, select Distribution and continue, and export the file it create.. `ipa file was around 14 mb.`